# Change of Affiliation before Publication

Tags: publications, affiliation

I was a student at a community college and did research as an undergrad at a small university. After finishing up my summer research, I continued to do poster presentations, all three of which I indicated my community college as my affiliation, as the research was funded through them. In addition, I was still at the community college.

Currently, I am not at a larger university and we are about to have our manuscript published. Do I need to change my affiliation to something else, or should I keep it as it is with my Community College.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple affiliations on a paper. When transitioning from one institute to another while working on a paper, it is common to list both institutes as affiliation. You should list all those places where a significant amount of work has been done. That is, if you run a study at institute A and write the paper while working at B, list both A and B.

If you are currently without any affiliation only mention your former place.

Comment: Almost all of my work was with my professor at his institute. For funding purposes, I had to technically use my home institute for the poster, but given that the latter was done without their funding, can I also use my professor's institute?

I'm not adding the current Institute I'm at. I just started my second half of getting my BS in Mechanical Engineering and I haven't done any work here regarding the publishing.

Comment: Have you been working/studying/employed at your home institute? If yes, better add both. Would there be a problem adding it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I already have one institute listed, but I honestly don't see why not to add my prof's institute as mine as well, given I worked there. It might actually help him more.

Comment: As said in my answer, add both then.